# Converting Wndows Form to Windows User Control

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm converting a Windows Form into a Windows User Control.

Basically I'm changing the inherit (FrmHome : UserControl)

I'm now making the code completion in order to fix the compilation errors but I'm having trouble to adapt the mdiParent property.

In Windows Form I was using the following code:

```
FrmHome frm = new FrmHome();
        frm.MdiParent = this; (Update parent/child form)
        frm.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        frm.Show();


FrmAdmin frm = new FrmAdmin();
        frm.MdiParent = this.MdiParent; (between container child forms)
        frm.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        frm.Show();
```

Since I'm using the User Control, how this is suppose to be?

Thank you!

Comment: I'm trying to use the property ActiveMdiChild but I can't relate with the form context. Can someone give a hand please? Thanks

Comment: I don't think "User Control" and "MDI" belong together, which is why the code is fighting you. It's not a use case that's provided for. (Also, if you want to clarify your question, you can *[edit]* it - there's no need to write comments responding to yourself)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever yeah they are not related but it seems there is other property called activeMdiChild but I cannot get it working. Thank you for the help

Comment: The point is, MDI is about a *window* containing one or more other windows. That's why you get MDI related features when you derive from `Form`, since that's the .NET abstraction for windows, and why you won't find the same functionality when you derive from `UserControl` instead.

Comment: Instead of setting the `MdiParent` you need to add the control to a container. For example `uc1 = new UserControl1(); uc1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill; this.panel1.Controls.Add(uc1);`

Comment: @RezaAghaei I figured it out! Thanks
How do I make your answer as correct?